# Install win8.1 from win7

Tags: windows-8, windows-installation

I'd like to install win 8.1 on a different hard drive along with my current win 7. Can I simply mount the win8.1 iso (daemon-tools) and install it from Windows 7, or do I have to burn a dvd first?